# Magento 1.8 - Display block in email template

Tags: magento-1.8, template, blocks, email

I try to display a custom block in email template and pass the order object. I tried

> {{block type='module/blockname' area='frontend' order=$order
>   template='template/module.phtml'}}

Block is like:

> Namespace_Module_Block_Blockname extends Mage_Core_Block_Template

The module.phtml exists and using it in another phtml with

> Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock("module/blockname");

works fine. But in email template the block won't show up. Do i miss some configuration in layout.xml? I tried so many things to get this working, perhaps someone can give me a hint how to manage this.

I also tried with layout handle:

```
<some_handle>
    <block type="module/blockname" name="blockname" template="namespace/template.phtml"></block>
</some_handle>
```

and call with:

> {{layout area="frontend" handle="some_handle" order=$order}}

Answer (score 2):

I know that you can include static blocks using e.g.:

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="static-block-id" }}
```

That block simply uses `_toHtml()` to output the content from the static block.

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $blockId = $this->getBlockId();
    ...
    return $html;
}
```

Similarly, you could try and populate the `_toHtml()` function with HTML in your module to output what ever you need to output. You cannot use PHP variables such as `$order` to pass in your data for processing.

Comment: From Magento 1.9. this works but don't forget to add cms/block to the allowed blocks (System > Permissions > Blocks).

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing the same problem as I am you might have forgotten to white list your block... You need to add an entry in the permission_block table with your block path.

Comment: Specifically allow `cms/block` under System -> Permissions -> blocks