# Using variables in static block for email template

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, email-templates, static-block

I used a [static block in my email templates](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18747/magento-1-8-display-block-in-email-template)

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="mail_include_header"}}
```

Now I would like to use variables like `{{var logo_url}}` in that block but it does not resolve it. Instead `{{var logo_url}}` get's printed out into the mail.

I would like Magento to show the logo url.

I tried things like

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="mail_include_header" logo_url="{{var logo_url}}"}}
```

Of course this only breaks it completely... I read that you can pass variables using the xml layout but no idea [what layout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36756/what-layout-xml-is-used-for-email-templates) is used here.

I also tried:

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="mail_include_header" logo_url=$logo_url }}
```

But that also did not work.

**Update: Half solved**

Feels like this is a bug because this is working:

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="mail_include_header" }}
{{var logo_url}}
```

If I use the variable in the mail template I can also use it in the included block. Otherwise I can not. Still I did not found the responsible code in `app/code/core`.

As a workaround I will include and hide the needed variables in the main template. Until someone can bring some light into this:

```
<div style="display:none;">{{var logo_url}} {{var logo_alt}}</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logo_url variable is only available to the email template and not to the cms block.

What you could do is: 
Create a custom variable under System->Custom Variables called logo_url and then include: {{customVar code="logo_url"}} in your block.

In addition you could set:

```
{{media url="email/logo/"}}{{config path="design/email/logo"}}
```

if you have uploaded a logo.

Or

```
{{skin url="images/logo_email.gif"}}
```

if you are using the skin directories.

Comment: That is nice but does not work for me. I have two stores and the custom variables are always global for all stores.

Comment: @PiTheNumber Has this changed in ce 1.9? I have a store view switcher when I edit a custom variable.

I have updated the answer with other options available.

Comment: Oh, right. It shows after save. Thanks, that would work!

Answer (score 1):

The right way is:

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="mail_include_header" logo_url="$logo_url" }}
```

with "".

It's work for me.